# Ngx infinite scrolling - Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'infiniteScrollDistance' since it isn't a known property

Tags: angular, infinite-scroll

I installed ngx infinite scrolling [ngx-InfiniteScroll](https://github.com/orizens/ngx-infinite-scroll) using :

```
  npm install ngx-infinite-scroll --save
```

In my app.module I added :

```
import {InfiniteScrollModule} from 'ngx-infinite-scroll';
```

And in my imports I added :

```
  imports: [
 BrowserModule,
 FormsModule,
 AppRoutingModule,
 BrowserAnimationsModule,
 InfiniteScrollModule,
 NgbModule.forRoot()
]
```

And then in my component.ts I added again :

```
 import { InfiniteScrollModule } from 'ngx-infinite-scroll';
```

In my html I have :

```
<div class="col-md-12 tableDiv" infiniteScroll [infiniteScrollDistance]="2" [infiniteScrollThrottle]="100" (scrolled)="onScroll()">
  /*table with content here */
```

And the error I get is that infiniteScrollDistance isn't a known property of 'div', and can't bind to it .
What I am doing wrong ? 
What step am I missing ? 
I have used it before and it has worked. But now I can't seem to get it to do so.
Any hint ?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you added it to the main module instead of the shared module.

```
app.module.ts
```

instead of

```
shared.module.ts
```

If your component is in the shared module.

also:

in this example the syntax is different:

```
<div class="search-results" infinite-scroll
```

instead of:

```
<div class="search-results" infiniteScroll
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-infinite-scroll-rz1jjz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts